# Browser preview in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I see in many videos how the web applications are run on server in Exclipse and are previewed inside the IDE, without opening the actual browser. Is that possible in Netbeans?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is possible. From the menu go to `Tools->Options`. In the `General` tab you see the `Web Browser` setting. Select the `Embedded WebKit Browser`.

Comment: I tried this and restarted NetBeans but nothing seems to have changed. What do I do next?

Comment: Find a html file in the Projects, Files, or Favorites tab, right-click on the file and select View. A tab should open alongside with your source files, showing the file as in a browser.